# Sonicwall with SSO LDAP failing intermittently

Tags: sonicwall

So using LDAP to limit what AD groups can get to the internet. It works great, for about a week, and then LDAP stop working. If I go into the sonicwall and change it to LDAP 2 and then back to LDAP 3 it magically starts working again. It's very annoying, I've had cases in with support, but so far no dice....

grr....

Comment: any logs on sonicwall or ldap server?

Comment: Are you using the SonicWALL SSO agent on your LDAP server(s)?

Comment: The sonicwall just gives a generic, unable to contact LDAP server. Immediately after flipping to version 2 and then back to version 3, something gets reset and it works again.

Comment: The SSO agent is installed on a separate server